# How to connect SQLServer 2012 to php

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2012

I am trying to connect PHP with MSSQL Server 2012. But unable to establish connection. I've latest version of php installed in my windows 7 PC. I tried to run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` php script which is working fine but when I tried to connect MS SQL Database, I am unable to connect. Here's my simple php script to establish connection :

```
<?php
    $server = "ADMIN-PC\admin";
    $options = array(  "UID" => "sa",  "PWD" => "password123",  "Database" => "Example");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);
    if ($conn === false) 
        die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    echo "Successfully connected!";
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Anything wrong with the code..?? Also search on google, tried other examples and gone through php manual but same issue. Please suggest me solution.

Comment: "I am unable to connect": in what way: error, timeout or something else: tell us!

Comment: @Richard nothing displays..just blank screen. If I write echo "somthing"; before connection string then it will print. But after connection string nothing displays.